# Active Scaffold dynamic action link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activescaffold

Maybe someone know of a way to make a dynamic hide/show filter action link that changes on click without writing any javascript or creating partials, just with controller and helpers.

So instead of having two buttons:

```
config.action_links.add :index, :label=>"Hide", :parameters => {:cancelled => false}, :position => false
config.action_links.add :index, :label=>"Show", :parameters => {}, :position => false
```

It would be awesome to have a dynamic button that changes on click from hide - show

Answer (score 0):

The important piece is that when you change links, even by using :dynamic_parameters attribute, they won't get re-rendered unless you specify

`config.list.refresh_with_header = true`

in your configuration. Once you do that, it's just code.

In my case, I have a list of records with optional attached documents. I want to toggle between showing a list of all the records and just the ones with attachments. I have a boolean parameter `:with_attachments` that is either `'0'` or `'1'`.

The action links look like

```
config.action_links.add :index, label: 'Show All', parameters: { with_attachments: '0' }, position: false
config.action_links.add :index, label: 'Attachment Only', parameters: { with_attachments: '1' }, position: false
config.list.refresh_with_header = true # Refresh action buttons!
```

The index method applies the `hidden` tag to the currently selected option.

```
def index
  current = params[:with_attachments] || '0'
  active_scaffold_config.action_links.each do |link|
    # For :index actions (filtering the list)
    if link.action == :index
      # hide the one that would refresh with the current parameter value
      link.html_options[:hidden] = (link.parameters[:with_attachments] == current)
    end
  end
  super
end
```

And then there is CSS that makes hidden actions invisible

```
.active-scaffold-header .actions a[hidden=hidden] {
  display: none;
}
```

You could probably do it with just one button and :dynamic_parameters but since I have icons attached via CSS (omitted for simplicity) that solution wouldn't work for me.